# How to judge a better app

Tags: applications, security, privacy

I installed a verity of android apps in my android device. And almost all apps require verity of permissions. Apart from these, these days we’re doing online transactions on android smartphones and using banking apps also.

In such scenario, please guide me that which android apps is vulnerable or malware or Trojan.

Also please guide me that how I can be assured with security of my android device.

My android device is 4.4.2 and its rooted.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty had to give a list of malicious android app.

In general: always download appss from [play store](https://play.google.com/store), Google check all these apps with an antivirus.

Furthermore some app can be open-source (generally it's in the description) but if you want a list you can get [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/). Nearly all apps exist in opensource version: OSMand (GPS), FaceSlim (Facebook), OpenTasks (ToDoList), QKSMS (sms app), Red Moon (blue screen filter), Syncthing (file synchronisation) etc...

As you have a rooted device, there are some apps that allow you to uncheck app permission (as Android 6) a little google search will give you results (you may certainly need BusyBox)

Also there is the excellent Xposed framework that propose (if I remember) some modules to get rid of some permission.

Be aware that sometimes disabling permission may block the app, just give back the permission to restore.

I'm sory I can't provide you more link cause I've got too low reputation.

Comment: My device is rooted. I am using paid Kaspersky Internet Security for Android, Malwarebytes Anti-Malware App and Xposed Xprivacy. Do I need to do anything more for device security and privacy?

Comment: @GNS - You have good security installed already. You may need an App locker on top of that. Personally I don't use any of that because I know what to click and what not to ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Homer pointed out, putting a list of confirmed malicious android apps together is impossible, within reason. You can, however,

- Disable App Permissions (In your case, you will need to download an AppOps Launcher from the play store. The are fine, they're shortcuts.)
- Use AntiVirus. I don't personally, But it can help.
- Ensure Google Play Services stays up-to-date, to get bug fixes and shizzle.
- Ensure your root manager is updated and working at 100%.
- Make Sure SELinux is 'enforcing'. (Type 'getenforce' into an emulator. It will either say '1' or 'enforcing'. I says neither of them, type 'su', grant root, then 'setenforce 1')

Comment: I do agree with all. As I mentioned earlier, I am using paid Kaspersky Internet Security for Android, Malwarebytes Anti-Malware App and Xposed Xprivacy for managing permissions.
Most of you prefer to download and update apps from Play Store. I do the same.
Even after downloading and updating an app from Play Store, there are some apps (e.g. Clean Master) which is known as a Malware by some expert users. Like this app, I would like to judge suspicious apps.